# Custom validator Client Side Manipulation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a custom validator named cuvYesNo. It's used against a telerik control named optYesNo. When neither the Yes or No option is selected the validator fires correctly and displays a red "*required" message on screen. I then select the "Yes" option and the red "*required" message does not go away even though the page is valid and can be submitted. So I need a way to access the custom validator to hide the error message when either "Yes" or "No" is selected. How can I gain a reference to the validator from the telerik OnClicked Event? The below code does not clear the "*required" message even though the even fires

```
function optYesNoClicked(sender, args) {
    alert("optYesNo fired");
    var x = document.getElementById("<%= cuvYesNo.ClientID%>");
    x.IsValid = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, 5 minutes after I posted this and idea popped into my head. I did a view source and see that the custom validator is being rendered as a span tag, so I just added this line of code

```
x.style.display = "none";
```